# how to specify length of the column values whil creating a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This is how I tried to create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE namevalues
        (
          seqid integer NOT NULL,
          name text(50) NOT NULL,
          value text(50),
          CONSTRAINT namevalues_pkey PRIMARY KEY (seqid, name)
        );
```

I tried doing this but this doesn't work. could anyone please tell how should I specify the length?

Comment: Try to use varchar(50) instead text(50): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-character.html.

Comment: ok and what if my column is of type integer?

Comment: `integer` has a fixed range, and therefore it's storage requirements are known in advance, you can't change it

Comment: `text` is unlimited, you could use `character varying` _data type_ to allocate space.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev: although not relevant here: please don't link to outdated versions of the manual. Use `current` instead of the version number: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: and you must read [important database designing rules](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359654/important-database-designing-rules-which-I-fo)

Comment: @SharmishthaKulkarni, maybe this link will be useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 1):

The `TEXT` type in PostgreSQL does not have a size. You can fix it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE namevalues
    (
      seqid integer NOT NULL,
      name text NOT NULL,
      value text,
      CONSTRAINT namevalues_pkey PRIMARY KEY (seqid, name)
    );
```

or use `VARCHAR(50)` instead of `TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use varchar(50) instead of text(50).
>
> Because,

**[PostgreSQL API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) says `text` data type does't have size, it allow variable with unlimited length**

```
    CREATE TABLE namevalues
    (
      seqid integer NOT NULL,
      name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      value varchar(50),
      CONSTRAINT namevalues_pkey PRIMARY KEY (seqid, name)
    );
```

**[Reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/String-Functions/lengthsReturnsthenumericlengthofcharacterstrings.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `text`, you want `varchar`...

```
CREATE TABLE namevalues
(
  seqid integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT namevalues_pkey PRIMARY KEY (seqid, name)
);
```

From the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html)...

> text: variable unlimited length

Comment: `integer` has a fixed range, and therefore it's storage requirements are known in advance, you can't change it.  If you want to change the precision/decimal places a number has then use `numeric` for example...